# PyMC multiple linear regressions

Tags: python, linear-regression, pymc

I'm trying to fit several lines sharing the same intercept.

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc

# Observations
a_actual = np.array([[2., 5., 7.]]).T
b_actual = 3.
t = np.arange(100)
obs = np.random.normal(a_actual * t + b_actual)


# PyMC Model
def model_linear():
    b = pymc.Uniform('b', value=1., lower=0, upper=200)

    a = []
    s = []
    r = []
    for i in range(len(a_actual)):
        s.append(pymc.Uniform('sigma_{}'.format(i), value=1., lower=0, upper=100))
        a.append(pymc.Uniform('a_{}'.format(i), value=1., lower=0, upper=200))
        r.append(pymc.Normal('r_{}'.format(i), mu=a[i] * t + b, tau=1/s[i]**2, value=obs[i], observed=True))

    return [pymc.Container(a), b, pymc.Container(s), pymc.Container(r)]

model = pymc.Model(model_linear())
map = pymc.MAP(model)
map.fit()
map.revert_to_max()
```

The computed MAP estimates are far from the actual values. Those values are also very sensitive to the lower and upper bounds of `sigmas` and `a`, to the actual values of `a` (e.g. `a = [.2, .5, .7]` will give me good estimates) or to the number of lines to do the regression on.

Is this the right way of performing my linear regressions?

ps : I tried to use an Exponential prior distribution for sigmas but results were not better.

Comment: Can you not just run 3 separate linear regressions?

Comment: I can't as each observation needs to share the same intercept (`b`). My real model is more complicated than that; this is a simplified version of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think using MAP might not be your best bet. If you are able to do a proper sampling then consider replacing the last 3 lines of your example code with

```
MCMClinear = pymc.MCMC( model)
MCMClinear.sample(10000,burn=5000,thin=5)
linear_output=MCMClinear.stats()
```

Printing the `linear_output` for this gives very accurate inferences for the parameters.

Comment: Yes, the MCMC sampling is working fine and giving good results. I was just wondering why the MAP estimates were so sensitive to variable bounds or to the actual values of the observation on a simple model. Using the [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/) library (which is also based on scipy's optimize package) is giving good results for the same problem.